# Official study for importance of performance

Tags: response-time

I read a lot that the performance of a site or a program is really important for the impression on the user and their decision to buy something/come back again later.

While this is logical, I wasn't able to find a study on this. I found a lot recommendations to work on the performance, and some companies published stories where they explain that this helped them to increase their profit - but I'm not able to find a normal study on this.

Such a study should give a detailed overview about what percentage of users become unhappy and don't visit the site again after which time spend or should at least proof that such a correlation exists.

Comment: By official do you mean done or sponsored by a government? by a reputable company or institution? who is considered reputable for this, a marketing company or a big name regardless of business orientation?

Comment: It doesn't have to be done by a government, but someone "generally reputable". Any company would be fine, as long as they aren't simply telling their own story of success without any hard facts or are actually selling performance optimization tools

Comment: Well, then you have many, The Nielsen article is a good guide, but it's times are based on an era where 20Kb was considered a limit for page size. Not to mention that as far as I remember, he hasn't done any test about it but used references from other authors. In any case, I'll check the books I have from him to refresh my memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest I've seen is [from the Nielsen Norman Group's website.](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/)

Relevant section:

- **0.1 second** is about the limit for having the user feel that the system is reacting instantaneously, meaning that no special feedback is necessary except to display the result.
- **1.0 second** is about the limit for the user's flow of thought to stay uninterrupted, even though the user will notice the delay. Normally, no special feedback is necessary during delays of more than 0.1 but less than 1.0 second, but the user does lose the feeling of operating directly on the data.
- **10 seconds** is about the limit for keeping the user's attention focused on the dialogue. For longer delays, users will want to perform other tasks while waiting for the computer to finish, so they should be given feedback indicating when the computer expects to be done. Feedback during the delay is especially important if the response time is likely to be highly variable, since users will then not know what to expect.

Answer (score 2):

- [Akamai’s eCommerce Web Site Performance Study Results](http://www.ppc-buyers.com/akamais-ecommerce-web-site-performance-study-results/). mentions some data gathered by this content delivery network. The blog post has a link to the original study, althugh you have to register to download it.

  - Consumers become impatient when pages take longer than 2 seconds to load:
  - 47% expect to wait no more than 2 seconds for a Web page to render
  - 52% said that quick page loading is important to their site loyalty
  - 61% who spend more than $1,500 online per year insist on pages loading quickly
- [Twinkle100 web performance study](http://www.slideshare.net/MeasureWorks/twinkle100-web-performance-study). This slideshare document talks about a study that a dutch company did in 2010. You can download the original study [here](http://www.measureworks.nl/download/PDF/MeasureWorks-Twinkle-100-Benchmark-2010.pdf)
- The 2013 survey from compuware, [This holiday season 3 seconds will make the difference between winning & losing mobile shoppers!](http://apmblog.compuware.com/2013/11/19/this-holiday-season-3-seconds-will-make-the-difference-between-winning-losing-mobile-shoppers/) has some data about user opinion on performance. Their study mentions that 37% will leave a shopping site if it takes more than 3 seconds to load.

There are many studies like the ones I mention above on Internet, older Gomez studies, other CDN networks, Nielsen, etc.